# Using < in django template

Tags: html, django, sublimetext2

I have a newbie question. I've been recently trying out Django, and I notice that if I ever write a template tag of the sort:

```
{% if some_var < 10 %}
```

the `<` symbol is highlighted in sublime almost as if it's a syntax error (or warning). Now of course it works correctly, but I'm wondering why this highlighting occurs in the first place. Do some browsers have difficulty parsing `<` when reading HTML code or something? Please enlighten me (and `>` doesn't get highlighted to make matters worse!).

I'm actually considering writing a custom template tag that performs the "is less than" comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime probably thinks your template is a plain HTML file, in which case `<` and `>` are elements of HTML tags and don't make sense anywhere else.

You might be able to manually set the filetype to be a Django template which should fix the highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I made a back button with the label `<< back`, and a next button with the label `next >>`. I tested them on a *proxy browser* for mobile (i.e. Opera Mini), and found out that the back button wouldn't show at all (although the next one worked). I changed the label to simply `back` and it started appearing. After that experience, I've been paranoid that having `<` in the HTML template is somehow wrong and causes edge cases to fail; although `>` is fine. I guess your explanation partially answers why I saw what I saw while testing in Opera Mini.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`Djaneiro`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Djaneiro) package. It contains an `HTML (Django)` syntax definition that contains scopes for template tags:

[image: Djaneiro with Neon]

(The color scheme is my [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), which contains colors specifically for Djaneiro)

Another option is to upgrade to [Sublime Text 3](https://sublimetext.com/3), which is highly recommended anyway. The default HTML syntax definition (along with many other languages, including JavaScript, PHP, and Python) has been completely rewritten, and template tags are now ignored:

[image: HTML with Neon]

Comment: Thanks for this, though technically, my question was more around *why* is `<` flagged. If there are edge cases I'm missing, I'd just port it to a custom template tag that handles the `less than` case. I hope that doesn't cause a performance compromise.

Comment: The reason *why* the tag is highlighted in ST2 is because the HTML definition is wrong, and it is mistakenly highilighting as errors unpaired `<` characters. This definition has been fixed in ST3, hence the lack of highlighting when the character is inside a template tag. Sorry I wasn't more clear, you question was written as a problem to be solved, not an inquiry to be answered.